# Есть ли способ изменить только состояние переменного в StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

если я вызываю `setState` то, как я понял, меняется полностью состояние виджета, а есть ли метод который меняет только состояние одного переменного, так как я в будущем планирую запустить цикл который ежесекундно (или даже меньше) будет менять одну переменную, в этом случае думаю не стоит менять состояние полностью виджета? если есть то подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> если я вызываю setState то, как я понял, меняется полностью состояние
> виджета

Да, правильно поняли.

---

У вас есть 2 варианта решения вашего вопроса:

1. Создать отдельный `StatefulWidget` с циклом. Тогда при `setState` (внутри этого виджета) будет обновляться именно этот виджет.
2. Использовать [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html), который по сути делает тоже самое что и 1 вариант.

Пример 2 варианта:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int counter = 0;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) => Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(counter.toString()),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        counter++;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: а если кнопка запуска цикла стоит в `appBar`е а текст в `body`?

Comment: Тогда лучше использовать state management и отделить логику от UI: Redux, BLoC, MobX...

Comment: спасибо большое!